# The limit of esotericism

Tags: hadith-interpretation, source-identification

The following is a hadith from the Prophet ﷺ

> "The Quran possesses an external appearance and a hidden depth, an exoteric meaning and an esoteric meaning. This esoteric meaning in turn conceals an esoteric meaning so it goes on for seven esoteric meanings (seven depths of hidden depth)

Where can we find it? On what criteria can esoteric interpretations be valid and accepted? How can we determine what's eisegesis and distortion?

Comment: Why should the last paragraph be edited out? It's a genuine concern

Comment: You are free to discuss issues like that in [chat], but in order to be useful the main site needs to stay focused on answerable questions rather than subjective opinions. Tangents like that distract from the actual question asked, and are more likely result in arguments and debate rather than a helpful answer.